# how to get count of collection in blueprism

Tags: blueprism

I am struggling to to get number of rows count from collection variable in Blueprism. Actually I have connected MS access database and ran a query, I am storing the query results in some(X) collection variable.  Now I need to know how many rows got pulled.  somebody please help me on getting rows count from collection variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked the object "Collections"? That's the standard one that is developed by BluePrism company. It's one of the last objects, when you're scrolling through the list of the objects in "action" block.

Action name is "Count Rows" from standard Blue Prism "Collections" object.

Comment: Thank you Andrzej for the quick response.

Comment: Actually I found "Count Rows" function under collection object.  when I tried to assign collection variable name at "Collection name" under "Inputs" tab, it is not accepting and throwing a  warning message saying that "the required datatype is Text but the data type of [<Collection Variable name>] is collection.  I am not sure why it is not accepting collection variable since we supposed to give collection variable and how can it could be text variable? I dont understand the logic. am I missing something here?

Comment: Ah, there's a twist that I didn't explain. This action requires to have name of collection as an input, instead of whole collection.

If your collection is named [Coll1], then as an input use "Coll1", and it should work.

That's really strange design, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, is it...?? I never thought of it.  now I gave collection variable name in quotations and it is working.... thank a ton Andrzej.  Honestly I am struggling to find the solution for this but couldn't get anywhere.  You are awesome man, you made my day...:-)

Answer (score 2):

> Have you checked the object "Collections"? That's the standard one that is developed by BluePrism company. It's one of the last objects, when you're scrolling through the list of the objects in "action" block.

> Action name is "Count Rows" from standard Blue Prism "Collections" object

there's a twist, This action requires to have name of collection as an input, instead of whole collection. If your collection is named `[Coll1]`, then as an input use `Coll1`, and it should work. That's really strange design

If your collection name has a space in it such as Collection 1 then you will need to put quotations around this. E.g "Collection 1"

Answer (score 0):

Please check collections under internal objects. There you can find Count Rows.